# Blazor Server with Microsoft Identity in IIS with virtual application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, blazor, microsoft-identity-platform

I've created a Blazor Server project using the standard Visual Studio 2022 template with authentication set to Microsoft Identity. It works locally without issue.

When I try to deploy it to the default website on an IIS server in a virtual application, it gives the following error:

[image]

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? 
builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

I think it is an issue with the return url, because the virtual application name is added to the address automatically. I have this url included in my app registration, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to enable https in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I think after you see the error message page above, you may try to visit `http://localhost` or maybe you change the default home page url so `http://localhost/the_word_you_covered` and see if the user already signed in successfully.

I created a new Blazor server application with `Microsoft Identity`, then I fill the `appsettings.json` with `tenant id, client id`, and leave the CallbackPath as `/signin-oidc` by default. And in AAD, set redirect URL as `https://localhost/signin-oidc`. It worked well when test locally. After published to IIS, the sign in didn't work well so I comment the

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

and content in the so that I can see more error issue.

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) { }
```

But after doing these steps, everything worked well except the sign in redirect back to `http://localhost/signin-oidc`. Pls note here we need to set the redirect URL as `http` in Azure AD portal because IIS uses `HTTP` by default. But since there's no page routing to `signin-oidc`.

=========================================

If what I said above is not the issue, I'm afraid you can create a self-signed certificate and bind it to the default website, then visiting `https` instead. Just now I tried again and it keep showing 500 error like screenshot below. Then I create self-signed certificate to use https then solved the 500 error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am inexperienced with self-signed certs. How would it affect other virtual applications on the default website?

Comment: I'm afraid  the self-signed certificate can only be used for the test purpose, but it should bind to the port. If you publish several other applications into one IIS website, since they use the same port, other apps will also be able to use https to visit.